# How to use psql as postgres (asks for password, but I don't have one)?

Tags: macos, postgresql, psql

I have installed Postgres using HomeBrew and I try to create a new user in it.

I try to use `psql` to create a new user and database in Postgres, so first I try to open up it by using `sudo -u postgres psql`, but it prompts me for a password. As far as I know there should be no password for this user by default.

I also tried to edit my `pg_hba.conf`, but this also seems fine for me:

```
  # "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
  local   all             all                                     trust
  # IPv4 local connections:
  host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
  # IPv6 local connections:
  host    all             all             ::1/128                 trust
  # Allow replication connections from localhost, by a user with the
  # replication privilege.
  local   replication     all                                     trust
  host    replication     all             127.0.0.1/32            trust
  host    replication     all             ::1/128                 trust
```

Why does it keep prompting me a password (if there is a password what should be it)? If I simply try to run `psql` to log in using my current system user instead of `postgres`, and then provide my current user's password, that doesn't work either (I am on macOS by the way).

Comment: Are you sure you're not being asked for a password by the `sudo` command rather than the PostgreSQL server? Have you tried `su` (enter root password) followed by `su postgres` to switch to the postgres account?

Comment: Did you reload your conf files after modifying `pg_hba.conf`? `pg_ctl -D $PGDATA reload`. Also, homebrew IIRC creates a non-"postgres" superuser by default, perhaps try using that role via `psql -U <youruser> -d postgres`

Comment: Thank you guys for your replies. For future reference: Unfortunately I couldn't resolve my issue neither by using `su` or reloading the conf files. I have uninstalled Postgres from Homebrew and installed [Postgres.app](https://postgresapp.com/) instead, which works fine for now (it has a gui, by which I can initiate a `psql` console. This is unfortunate and I will investigate it later on, but for now this solution works.